# convert json object to htmlTable typescript

Tags: typescript, html-table, json

i want to convert my json object to a table, display in html page. I use typescript to do it. I have any informations about the subject, i just found a piece of solution in javascript here:http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2015/07/convert-json-data-html-table-jquery-datatables-plugin.html
Is it an example or a solution about?
thanks for advance

Comment: You want to transform data from one format to another, but what problem do you have?

Comment: how to convert json object to table in typescript.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to learn how to code in typescript?  If so, this might get you started:

```
let input = {
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "designation": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      "joining_date": "2011/07/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extension": "8422"
    }
 ]
}

function convert(data: typeof input) {
    let rows = data.data.map(d => `<tr><td>${d.name}</td></tr>`);
    return `<table>${rows}</table>`;
}

console.log(convert(input));
```

Comment: thanks Corey, i will try with it. I hope it's the same function i ought to use if i retrieved json object from a remote server.

Comment: Doesn't matter where the input comes from :)
Good luck!